# Double classes in Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

When looking through Foundation CSS, I've noticed

```
.row .row{}
```

What's the purpose of having a double class?
Is it a class of "row" with an element with "row" inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say is searching for:

- Any element with class `.row`

  - Inside any element with class `.row`

Why some can use this? To obtain more specificity and control for elements so if you have for example a table with the class .row on `tr` and inside that tr another table you can be more specific like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row"><td>
      Hi I'm outside
   <table>
      <tr class="row"><td>Hi I'm inside</td></tr>
   </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

.row {
  background:red;
}
.row .row{
  background:orange;
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RB2RL/)